# How to use querystring for wherebetween? Knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I'm pretty sure this should be the best idea to solve the problem I'm facing right now,
using wherebetween().

But I'm not sure how I could use it.

I've gotta deal with a querystring ?from=2020-03-15T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&to=2020-03-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z

To print the data between 3-15 and 3-20.

There is an and expression in the middle of from and to.

```
.modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (req.query.industry) {
          queryBuilder.where('industry',"like",`%${req.query.industry}%`);
      }
  })
```

This is the code that I've used for single querystring, but not sure how to work with it for multiple query strings.

```
.modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (req.query.from && req.query.to) {
          queryBuilder.whereBetween('timestamp',[`%${req.query.from}%`,`%${req.query.to}%`]);
      }
  })
```

this is what i have came up with so far, seems like its working but not printing anything...

seems like the problem is caused by the form the date is writte, is there any way I could use 2020-03-15T00%3A00%3A00.000Z as 2020-03-15T00:00:00Z

Comment: Is there any way I could only grab the 2020-03-15 from 2020-03-15T00%3A00%3A00.000Z and use it for wherebetween?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to use decodeuricomponent function?

Comment: If you know what kind of SQL you are trying to generate, it helps a lot while working with knex.

Answer (score 0):

Does dropping those `%` symbols from query which are wildcards for `like` operator work?

```
queryBuilder.whereBetween('timestamp',[req.query.from, req.query.to]);
```